# Was OMC’s “How Bizarre” (1995) inspired by Anne Clark’s “Hope Road” (1987)?

Tags: history, style

Listening to the Anne Clark song “Hope Road” (1987, [YouTube](https://youtu.be/cb0_hTDKYB4?t=60), from 01:00), I immediately had to think of OMC’s “How Bizarre” from (1995, [YouTube](https://youtu.be/C2cMG33mWVY?t=15), from 00:15).
The rhythm of the vocals is so similar in these songs that I find it hard to believe OMC didn’t copy it, given that both have a road trip theme.
However, I couldn’t find a connection between the two interpreters online (mentioning OMC being inspired by Anne Clark or similar).

Is this just that common a rhythm (and I’m not aware of it), or are my ears playing tricks on me (and the similarity is very superficial and probably coincidental), or is this a case of creative reuse?

Answer (score 0):

According to [whosampled](https://www.whosampled.com/OMC/How-Bizarre/), OMC's How Bizarre only samples "Whoomp! (There It Is) (Instrumental) by Tag Team (1993)". It may just be a very similar rhythm, without directly sampling another song.

Comment: I don’t know how accurate whosampled are. They claim that the sampled part starts at 03:01 in How Bizarre. Around there, you start hearing the beat more clearly, and there is a vague similarity, but it’s nowhere near the same. Honestly, I don’t see it. But of course, you may be right.